# Sections instead of rows resulting a crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I wanted to have some spacing between my `TableView` cells so I've changed my `TableView` code to this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [_boxs count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

My problem is that my "add line \ object" code is crashing. What changes should I make to this code?

Problematic code:

```
SomeClass *newObject = [[SomeClass alloc]initWithTitle:@".....  
[_boxs addObject:newObject];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_boxs.count-1 inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];    
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:NO];    
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FirstDetailsSegue" sender:self ];
```

`-boxs` is a NSMutableArray.

This is the error I'm getting: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 7 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update'

Comment: What is _boxs in your code? And what is the crash? If you are using it as NSArray, change it to NSMutableArray and that will fix the crash.

Comment: `-boxs` is a NSMutableArray. This is the error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 7 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have switched your row and column in the line where you are creating `NSIndexPath`. You need to modify your code as,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:_boxs.count-1];
```

If you were planning to use only one section and multiple rows in that you should change your delegate methods to return only 1 section and `[_boxs count]` rows. In that case your code would have worked.

As per you comment, looks like you want to insert a new section and not a row. Try this,

```
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:_boxs.count-1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

You can remove your insertRow line from your code.

Comment: Actually it was one of my tries. Still getting an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (8) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (7), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).

Comment: @MikaStern, It is clear from the error message you got that, you are incrementing the number of sections array from 7 to 8 but you are not doing any insert sections. That is the error. You need to do an insertSection as shown in my answer.